# Angular 6 - add class when meets section

Tags: angular, html

I want to add class `.active` to element when i scroll down to section.
I have two sections, and i'm adding class active on click and `href="#o-nas` is moving me to a `<section id="o-nas">...</section>`. I want to scroll down page and change class active depending on scroll position.

How can I do that with Angular 6 ?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" (click)="goToTop()" routerLink="/">
      <img src="assets/logo_studio.png">
    </a>

    <div class="collapse float-right">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item" [class.active]="router.url == '/'">
          <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center"  (click)="goToTop()"  (mouseenter)="hover[0] = true" (mouseleave)="hover[0] = false" [class.active]="hover[0] && router.url !== '/'" routerLink="/">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            Strona główna
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [class.active]="router.url == '/#o-nas'" *ngIf="router.url !== '/video' && router.url !== '/galeria'">
          <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" (mouseenter)="hover[1] = true" (mouseleave)="hover[1] = false" [class.active]="hover[1] && router.url !== '/#o-nas'"  href="#o-nas">
            O Nas
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [class.active]="router.url == '/#kontakt'" *ngIf="router.url !== '/video' && router.url !== '/galeria'">
          <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" (mouseenter)="hover[2] = true" (mouseleave)="hover[2] = false" [class.active]="hover[2] && router.url !== '/#kontakt' " href="#kontakt">
            Kontakt
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [class.active]="router.url == '/galeria'">
          <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" (mouseenter)="hover[3] = true" (mouseleave)="hover[3] = false" [class.active]="hover[3] && router.url !== '/galeria'" routerLink="/galeria">Galeria</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item" [class.active]="router.url == '/video'">
          <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" (mouseenter)="hover[4] = true" (mouseleave)="hover[4] = false" [class.active]="hover[4] && router.url !== '/video'" routerLink="/video">Video</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I do not see any ``section`` in your html code example.

Comment: I described it, section is below in home.component.html with id=„o-nas”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the selected color according with the scroll page, you can compare your scroll with the section position.

I just made an example. Check this out.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-active-scroll

Comment: Hmm this edited is what i was looking for, i will be later at home and i will check this